# Ubuntu 16.04 taking a long time to boot

Tags: boot, 16.04

my Ubuntu 16.04 Xenial is taking much time to inicialize, I dont know why but it started after some recommended updates.

Here is my "/etc/default/grub":

```
# If you change this file, run 'update-grub' afterwards to update
# /boot/grub/grub.cfg.
# For full documentation of the options in this file, see:
#   info -f grub -n 'Simple configuration'

GRUB_DEFAULT=0
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=0
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT_QUIET=true
GRUB_TIMEOUT=10
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""

# Uncomment to enable BadRAM filtering, modify to suit your needs
# This works with Linux (no patch required) and with any kernel that obtains
# the memory map information from GRUB (GNU Mach, kernel of FreeBSD ...)
#GRUB_BADRAM="0x01234567,0xfefefefe,0x89abcdef,0xefefefef"

# Uncomment to disable graphical terminal (grub-pc only)
#GRUB_TERMINAL=console

# The resolution used on graphical terminal
# note that you can use only modes which your graphic card supports via VBE
# you can see them in real GRUB with the command `vbeinfo'
#GRUB_GFXMODE=640x480

# Uncomment if you don't want GRUB to pass "root=UUID=xxx" parameter to Linux
#GRUB_DISABLE_LINUX_UUID=true

# Uncomment to disable generation of recovery mode menu entries
#GRUB_DISABLE_RECOVERY="true"

# Uncomment to get a beep at grub start
#GRUB_INIT_TUNE="480 440 1"
```

System Specifications:

```
Processor: Intel® Core™ i5-3317U CPU @ 1.70GHz × 4 
Memory: 7,7 GiB
Graphics: Intel® Ivybridge Mobile
OS type: 64-bit
Disk: 476,2 GB
```

I also have an NVIDIA 740M video board but i dont use that.

EDIT ---

systemd-analyze

```
Startup finished in 3.767s (kernel) + 42.820s (userspace) = 46.587s
```

systemd-analyze blame

```
  9.882s dev-sda6.device
  9.612s apparmor.service
  9.377s plymouth-read-write.service
  8.150s nmbd.service
  7.525s samba-ad-dc.service
  6.517s NetworkManager-wait-online.service
  6.376s teamviewerd.service
  2.231s thermald.service
  2.219s NetworkManager.service
  2.217s accounts-daemon.service
  2.135s systemd-modules-load.service
  1.807s ModemManager.service
  1.799s systemd-udevd.service
  1.530s plymouth-start.service
  1.479s systemd-fsck@dev-disk-by\x2duuid-69da77aa\x2da78c\x2d4bbb\x2db9
  1.394s gpu-manager.service
  1.327s systemd-tmpfiles-setup-dev.service
  1.222s grub-common.service
  1.047s systemd-journald.service
  1.027s keyboard-setup.service
  1.005s upower.service
   933ms dev-loop0.device
   907ms console-setup.service
   864ms networking.service
   857ms lightdm.service
   815ms systemd-backlight@backlight:intel_backlight.service
   703ms udisks2.service
   699ms ufw.service
   684ms virtualbox.service
   594ms dev-loop2.device
   520ms systemd-logind.service
   510ms systemd-sysctl.service
   450ms home.mount
   429ms systemd-rfkill.service
   373ms polkitd.service
   370ms snapd.autoimport.service
   358ms smbd.service
   347ms wpa_supplicant.service
   347ms systemd-update-utmp.service
   340ms iio-sensor-proxy.service
   337ms colord.service
   301ms sys-kernel-debug.mount
   300ms dev-hugepages.mount
   279ms systemd-tmpfiles-setup.service
   273ms irqbalance.service
   272ms dev-mqueue.mount
   270ms systemd-journal-flush.service
   248ms snap-core-1577.mount
   241ms apport.service
   230ms ondemand.service
   229ms systemd-udev-trigger.service
   228ms alsa-restore.service
   226ms speech-dispatcher.service
   216ms pppd-dns.service
   215ms rsyslog.service
   214ms systemd-user-sessions.service
   198ms bluetooth.service
   181ms avahi-daemon.service
   166ms systemd-random-seed.service
   158ms user@1000.service
   152ms systemd-remount-fs.service
   148ms snap-anbox-15.mount
   128ms dev-disk-by\x2duuid-f724534f\x2dff65\x2d42cc\x2da0c1\x2d244c45a
   126ms systemd-timesyncd.service
   106ms dns-clean.service
   101ms setvtrgb.service
   100ms snap-anbox\x2dinstaller-10.mount
    92ms kmod-static-nodes.service
    21ms resolvconf.service
    16ms snapd.socket
     6ms ureadahead-stop.service
     4ms rc-local.service
     3ms rtkit-daemon.service
     3ms sys-kernel-config.mount
     3ms systemd-update-utmp-runlevel.service
     2ms sys-fs-fuse-connections.mount
     1ms plymouth-quit-wait.service
   479us dev-loop1.device
```

Comment: Add these commands outputs to your question: `systemd-analyze`, `systemd-analyze blame`.

Comment: @Ravexina Done!

Comment: Everything seems normal to me, 46 Sec is not so long!

Comment: @Ravexina My machine takes more than 1.5 minutes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After one week looking at system failures because my system needed 3 minutes to start and 1 minute to shutdown and asking me why some processes takes more than 3 sec to start, i tryed today the following :

boot in recovery, and choose then "resume the booting"

I could have a system starting in less than 30 secs.

I googled and saw that some users had to start in recovery mode because of graphical problems and to resume the booting. As workaround, they updated their GRUB with "quiet splash nomodeset". I did it,

```
gksudo gedit /etc/default/grub
```

and added the "nomodeset" at the line

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash nomodeset"
```

then

```
sudo update-grub
```

the result is :

```
systemd-analyze
Startup finished in 7.603s (kernel) + 8.130s (userspace) = 15.734
```

Answer (score 0):

This may not be the problem, it may even have nothing to do with it at all, but I solved it this way.

You may have some commands in files like `/etc/rc.local` or whatever /etc/init .config file runs on startup.

If you do have something there (and you've had it from before the "recommended updates" you speak of), then it's very possible you need to check the script/commands you have in there and make sure nothing is causing this "long time".

Alternatively, if you have something like the following (look below), or anything related to superuser permissions for grub, in different files because you were trying to configure grub, that can cause a pretty long boot too:

`set superusers="userA"
password_pbkdf2 grub.<insanely long number or just normal password if you left pbkdf2 out>`

If something like this combines with a bunch of files from the older versions it slows down the boot, I can reassure that as it happened to me.

Concluding, if either one of these cases resembles your problem, then it is akin to mine and the only solution is to remove all unnecesary things from the grub configuration (I had to delete the old menu.lst for it to boot up faster) or fix the code in the files running on startup.

Comment: Hey there, thank you for your answer, i looked for /etc/rc.local but it is empty(only with few comments) and i dont have init.config or something like that(not that i know).
I didnt understand the second part, I never changed my boot options and my grub settings..
I think the long time is because of my video drivers, or my JVM/JRE/JDK things.. i changed my video board driver for "X.Org X Server (Open Source)" driver, then it improved a bit, but still taking more time than before, when the system was new :P

Comment: Sorry my answer didn't help with the problem but, when I though someone had the same hellish problem as I had some time ago, I just had to try xD. Oh well, good luck with the problem, happy bootings!

Comment: Thanks, I still looking for something that can make my system faster and boot faster.